# Why is classical physics not valid for a harmonic oscillator in its lowest energy state?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, probability, born-rule

I am reading Born's interpretation of wave function in quantum physics by [Eisberg & Resnick](http://www.google.com/#q=Eisberg+Resnick) and I am not able to understand this description about comparison between the classical and quantum validity for an oscillator at lowest energy.[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What parts you don't understand?

Comment: A large difference is in the fact that the lowest value of energy in classical mechanics is zero, while in the quantum case is not. You should state better which passages you don't understand for us to be able to answer. I don't have the book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are familiar with the concepts of eigenstates and eigenfunctions of a system in Quantum Physics. If not, I suggest you take the time to go back to the beginning of that same chapter of Eisberg-Resnick to gain a deeper understanding.

If one studies a harmonic oscillator system by means of Quantum Mechanics, they will find that the energy associated with the n-th eigenstate (let me regard the lowest energy one as the 0th) is

$\ E_n = ( n+ \frac{1}{2}) h \nu$

where $\nu$ is the frequency at which the system is oscillating.

So there is no possible energy level below $\frac{h \nu}{2}$ for a quantum harmonic oscillator, and to stress that peculiar phenomenon this value is called the *zero-point energy* of the oscillator. Obviously if you study the same system by a classical Physics point of view, this value can be neglected no matter how high the frequency (remember, $h$ is of the order of magnitude of $10^{-34} J s$) so the lowest possible energy becomes zero.

An important property of quantum systems is the [Correspondence Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correspondence_principle) which states that "the behavior of systems described by the theory of quantum mechanics [...] reproduces classical physics in the limit of large quantum numbers". In this case n is our quantum number: if n were large, we would be allowed to regard the oscillator as classical. But when you are dealing with small values of n, as certainly $n=0$ is, you cannot by any means resort to classical Physics.

This is why the book says: "When the oscillator is in its lower energy state we are very far from the range of validity of classical physics".